# About phpredis,I have been confused about how to choose the right branch for my PHP environment

Tags: php, linux

About phpredis,I have been confused about  how to choose  the right branch for my PHP environment

Now,my PHP environment  is  latest version `php 7.1.11`

all others  are right installed yet, like nginx  mysql ,and other extensions  like opcache

but  even if I had use the latest version redis-extension for php, the page is   `http://pecl.php.net/package/redis`
I use  this  **3.1.4    stable  2017-09-27  redis-3.1.4.tgz**

then after I execute the linux  comand like :

```
tar -xvf redis-3.1.4.tgz

cd redis-3.1.4

/usr/local/php71/bin/phpize

./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php71/bin/php-config && make && make install

and then  I restart the php-fpm,it throw  a messege like :

[root@3dd70b1a3ff2 redis-3.1.4]# /usr/local/php71/sbin/php-fpm

/usr/local/php71/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/redis.so doesn't appear to be a valid Zend extension
```

I had view  many docs , maybe  I should use the php7.1.9,but  I wanna  that if I can find a right source code in the github,then just fits the latest version php7.1.11

**the github page:  https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/tree/zinter-php71-reference**

Answer (score 0):

I have deal the question,nothing but the wrong config file,should use  extention=redis.so instead of zend_extension=redis.so

I should be more careful about the environment and configuration。